# c++ Help with reading in from stdin and to stdout . Also Operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdout, stdin

I need help regarding this portion of code...I am supposed to be passing two doubles to schmoo. if I do it like this "Schmoo(8.0,9.0);" it works find but when I try it as I have it, I get an error.  I am supposed to be reading input from cin which looks like this "add schmoo 8.0 7.0"  I think I am extracting the doubles wrong, how to extract each thing from cin properly. I need this to continue as long as their is input.

```
 while(cin){
    string command1 = "add schmoo";
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    double a,b;
    if(input == command1){
      cin >> a >> b;
      Schmoo *a = new Schmoo(a,b);
      c.insertFront(a);
    }
    string command2 = "throw mud";

    if(input == command2){
      cin >> a >> b;
      c.throwMudAt(a,b);
    }
```

Also i need help with overloading this opperator:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Schmoo &s){
  if(s.getMud() == 1){
    os << "Schmoo at (" << s.x << ", " << s.y << ") was hit mud " << mud << "time.";
  }
  os << "Schmoo at (" << s.x << ", " << s.y << ") was hit with mud" << mud << "times.";
  return os;
}
```

I am getting an error that has to do with s.getMud(); I've used get mud through a pointer before, but this class is no friend with any that has the pointer. but getMud is a function of the same class this is in, how do I use getMud(); in this context.

Comment: To make code look correctly, indent it by 4 spaces or select the code and hit the `{}` button above the text box.

Comment: There is a problem in your code: `double a,b; cin >> a >> b; Schmoo *a = new Schmoo(a,b);`

Answer (score 1):

`cin` reads until the first whitespace it encounters, so the `input` string will only be "add", not "add schmoo". Better read the first string, check if it is "add", then read the next string (you might want to add to more than schmoo) and then read the `double`s. Or change the command to "add_schmoo".

---

For your overload, how is the class `Schmoo` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming primarily from this line:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
```

If your input is `add schmoo 8.0 9.0`, then the `cin >> input` will not work, as you have given it no solid indication of when it should stop reading characters.

Comment: `cin` reads until the first space, so `input` will only contain "add".

Comment: I personally never use `cin` with strings, so I wasn't sure :). I usually use getline() instead.

Comment: what would be the soild identication? cin >> input >> input1 ;